# Load more data from the server using GET request

Tags: angularjs, http, mean-stack

I'm building a MEAN app.

I have an array stored in MongoDB and I would like to load it 20 items at a time (load on scroll).

For this to work, I would like to send a HTTP GET request with the index to start from in the body. However, I guess it is bad practice to do so (use the body in GET request).

Can anyone suggest another way?

Thanks

Comment: You have a document which has an array, or do you have several documents and want to paginate them? (document = mysql's row)

Comment: document which has an array

Comment: Then load the whole document and paginate the array in the front. Unless you tell me it's too heavy which I doubt

Comment: A GET call with one parameter (start index) is not at all a bad idea. You can go ahead with this way of lazy loading without any issues. Scroll and load.